# NextAuth /api/auth/* always return 404 on Vercel deployment but work locally

Tags: next.js, vercel, next-auth

Whenever I try to navigate to my sign-in page, it redirects to `/api/auth/error` on the vercel deployment. Locally, it navigates and works as expected.

From inspecting the network tab the first network request to fail is to `/api/auth/providers`

Not exactly sure where it's going wrong.

`/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts`

```js
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter';
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GithubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import LinkedInProvider from 'next-auth/providers/linkedin';

import prisma from 'utils/prismaClient';

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GithubProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
        }),
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
        }),
        LinkedInProvider({
            clientId: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
        }),
    ],
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    pages: {
        signIn: '/sign-in',
        error: '/sign-in',
    },
});
```

`/pages/sign-in.tsx`:

```js
type Props = {
    providers: Provider[];
};

const SignIn: NextPage<Props> = ({ providers }) => {
    const router = useRouter();

    const [authCallbackUrl, setAuthCallbackUrl] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
    const [error, setError] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!router.isReady) return;

        setAuthCallbackUrl(('/' + router.query.callbackUrl) as string);
        setError(router.query.error as string);
    }, [router.isReady, router.query.callbackUrl, router.query.error]);

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
                    <button
                        key={provider.name}
                        type="button"
                        onClick={async () => {
                            await signIn(provider.id, {
                                callbackUrl: authCallbackUrl,
                            });
                        }}
                    >
                        {getSvgByProvider(provider.name)}
                        Sign in with {provider.name}{' '}
                    </button>
                ))}
            </div>
            {error && <SignInError error={error as keyof typeof SIGNIN_ERRORS} />}
        </div>
    );
};

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const providers = await getProviders();
    return {
        props: { providers },
    };
}

export default SignIn;
```

Github Provider Callback Urls:
`${VERCEL_URL}/api/auth/callback/github`

I imagine there is nothing with my OAuth setup because it works locally? but not sure.

I've tried deploying with and without `NEXTAUTH_URL` in the env variables for Vercel but it has no effect as expected. According to documentation

> When deploying here, you do not need to explicitly set the NEXTAUTH_URL environment variable.

Any idea what is going wrong? It works locally but when I deploy it, as soon as I  call `signIn();` from the homepage it navigates to `api/auth/error`

Edit: After console.logging `providers` inside the Sign-in page, it returns null. Any idea why that is the case?

Edit 2: Seems this is something to do with deploying it on Vercel? I deployed the same application on Netlify with `NEXTAUTH_URL` env variable defined and it works

Comment: Can you show us the error you're getting?

Comment: Getting `CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR` error. I deployed the same application on Netlify with NEXTAUTH_URL env variable defined and it works.. looks like this could be something on Vercel's end or something to do with deploying it on Vercel?

Comment: Did you eventually find out what was wrong? I am experiencing the same problem.

Comment: @sciffany No... I wasn't able to find a solution to this problem so I switched to Netlify

Answer (score 0):

You have to put in the Vercel environment variables:

```
NEXTAUTH_URL="yourdomainevercel"
```

And above all, you have to redeploy your app so that it takes the variable into account.
It's not dynamic.

You must also have `Automatically expose System Environment Variables` checked in the Vercel settings
Once done, it works very well with `NEXTAUTH` and Vercel.