# Client fetch error next-auth NEXT.js and Vercel deploy with custom domain

Tags: next.js, vercel, next-auth

I have an e-commerce that I deploy into vercel, I used next-auth for authentication, when i  try to login it's complains and launch an error

[image]

`[nextauth].ts`

```
export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      name: "Custom Login",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "Correo:",
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "correo@google.com",
        },
        password: {
          label: "Contraseña:",
          type: "password",
          placeholder: "Contraseña",
        },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        console.log({ credentials });

        return await dbUsers.checkUserEmailPassword(
          credentials!.email,
          credentials!.password
        );
      },
    }),
```

`login.tsx`

```
const onLoginUser = async ({ email, password }: FormData) => {
    setShowError(false);

    await signIn("credentials", { email, password });

    
  };
```

this is my response:

```
[![2022-06-23T08:45:36.199Z 33d4ff25-ada2-4054-9050-68eec5626886    ERROR   \[next-auth\]\[error\]\[CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR\] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error invalid json response body at https://madrugon-8dxawm6jh-madrugon-admin.vercel.app/api/auth/session reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 {
  error: {
    message: 'invalid json response body at https://madrugon-8dxawm6jh-madrugon-admin.vercel.app/api/auth/session reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0',
    stack: 'FetchError: invalid json response body at https://madrugon-8dxawm6jh-madrugon-admin.vercel.app/api/auth/session reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0\n' +
      '    at /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/node-fetch/index.js:1:49606\n' +
      '    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)',
    name: 'FetchError'
  },
  path: 'session',][1]][1]
```

in heroku and locally works perfect but not in custom domain in vercel
¿can you help me?

[Link of custom domain](https://www.madrugonmayorista.co/)

[Link on heroku](https://madrugon.herokuapp.com/)

[My repo](https://github.com/FemtDeveloper/my-shop-next)

I have reviewed and it seems that one of my problems is that the providers are not read

Comment: Have you correctly configured your environment variables in Vercel?

Comment: I've been thinking about it and I've corrected it twice and it doesn't work. Could you look at the env.template and check if I'm ok

Comment: Ran into this issue as well: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72469610/nextauth-api-auth-always-return-404-on-vercel-deployment-but-work-locally

The issue may be related to deploying it on Vercel, maybe you could try deploying it elsewhere like Netlify to verify that the issue only happens on Vercel?

Comment: I deployed in Heroku and it works :(

Comment: So you had trouble with Vercel and ended up in Heroku? were you able to deploy again to Vercel or never tried again? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: How about trying it on Render (where I work)? You can use a custom domain. Here's a quickstart for Next.js that I hope will help: https://render.com/docs/deploy-nextjs-app