# NextAuth Email Provider returning Page Not Found + 404 on /api/auth/* + Client Fetch Error on Vercel

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel, next-auth

**Problem**

I'm trying to use NextAuth's Email Provider to create an authentication endpoint. It works locally. However, I get redirected to "404 | Page not found" on sign in on our live site.

This code used to work on Vercel a few days ago too.

**Code**

The following is the Auth handler and the Sign in button.

pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import { type NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import EmailProvider from 'next-auth/providers/email'

import { prisma } from '@onlyhelper/db'
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter'

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    EmailProvider({
      server: process.env.ALL_EMAIL_SERVER,
      from: 'hello@domainname.com'
    })
  ],
  secret: 'secret',
  session: {},
  callbacks: {
    session({ session, user }) {
      session.user.id = user.id
      return session
    }
  }
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

pages/login.tsx

```
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react'


return (
  <button onClick={() => signIn()}>
    Sign In
  </button>
)
```

**Errors**

The following are printed on the console in the "Page not found" page.

```
GET https://domainname/api/auth/error 404

GET https://domainname/api/auth/session 404

[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] 

https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

POST https://app.onlyhelper.com/api/auth/_log 404
```

**What I've tried**

- Searched Google and StackOverflow for similar problems

  - [NextAuth /api/auth/* always return 404 on Vercel deployment but work locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72469610/nextauth-api-auth-always-return-404-on-vercel-deployment-but-work-locally) This one comes closest, but has no answers.
- Set NEXTAUTH_URL env variable to production url on live site
- Set NEXTAUTH_SECRET to some string
- Made sure to return "session" object on session callback
- Downgrade next and nextauth to certain versions as suggested by people who encountered similar problems
- Made sure [...nextauth].ts is in the /pages/api/auth folder
- Made sure email server environment variable is correct
- Pointed local instance to production database, and logged in successfully, to confirm this isn't a database configuration/corrupted data issue

It's so strange because this used to work perfectly fine, and it still works locally. Wondering if it's a Vercel issue?

**Update**

Seems like all my API routes are returning 404 | Page not found. I still don't know what's causing this.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with VPS and Nginx... Did you managed to solve that issue?

Comment: No, we recreated the repo from scratch, moved all our changes, and the error disappeared.

Comment: recreated the folder and file again and it worked